# Overriding core forum function

Tags: 7

is there any clean way to override [_forum_topics_unread](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum.module/function/_forum_topics_unread/7) function call from [template_preprocess_forum_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum.module/function/_forum_topics_unread/7) without hacking the core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get tricky, you can use [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7), and unset the core preprocess and replace it with your own. Advanced Forum makes use of that, if you want to see an example.

Answer (score 5):

No, hardcoded function calls can not be replaced.

The only thing you can do is add your own preprocess function for "forum_list "(`yourmodule_preprocess_forum_list()`), and then call another function to overwrite the value returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

Core Override (http://drupal.org/sandbox/gielfeldt/1546970) allows you to override individual functions in core without patching core.